# Xamarin forms view optimization when IsVisible=false

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, responsive-design

I'm looking for best practice in order to optimize Xamarin Forms app when switching visibility of layouts in order to show them when screen resizing. Xamarin Forms loads any layout either if IsVisible=false. So, what I'm looking  to optimize my app is, load layouts when `IsVisible=True`, if it turns to `False`, is there a way to "unload" it so it does not take too much memory of a device? Because there's no problem with UWP, but there are phones with low memory.

Let's suppose I have next code:

```
    <StackLayout IsVisible="False" Orientation="Vertical">
        <!-- Make it visible when small screen -->
        <CustomView1></CustomView1>
        <CustomView2></CustomView2>
    </StackLayout>

    <StackLayout IsVisible="True" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <!-- Make it NON visible when small screen -->
        <CustomView1></CustomView1>
        <CustomView2></CustomView2>
    </StackLayout>
```

Xamarin would load same views 2 times. What I'm looking is like in web, remove it from the DOM (or dont load it in the DOM until it's visible), but for Xamarin Forms. So the app does not load the view when it does not need it, and I'm looking to have it while runtime, on the window app resize.

PS: It could be done by making use of OnIdiom.Phone, OnIdiom.Tablet and OnIdiom.Desktop, but this last, I could not have the view as desired if UWP window app resize.

Comment: Hi Esteban is your example code exactly what you want to render? Exactly the same views inside the layouts but in different orientation? Or is it just simple pseudo code to make your question easier to read? If it's the former  - you can bind the orientation property in your code behind itself.

When the page is first loaded use the Essentials.DeviceInfo class to get width and height and set orientation appropriate to screen size. For UWP, add a listener on window resize and change the orientation when it happens if needed. If this is what you want, I'll add an answer with code snippets.

Comment: What I was looking for was the use of ControlTemplate, check this post: https://www.xamboy.com/2019/01/18/using-control-templates-in-xamarin-forms/

Adam, it was pseudo code, yes. It's not about orientation, but I think control template does what I want

Comment: In your case , you could binding the value of IsVisible in code behind and change it in runtime .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> You can use Control Templates to change the appearance of a view/page at runtime. This is helpful if you want to re-theme pages or switch between views depending on the context. The property that allows to set a control template is called ControlTemplate which is available in ContentPage and ContentView classes.

Ref:
https://www.xamboy.com/2019/01/18/using-control-templates-in-xamarin-forms/

Comment: Does runtime IsVisible change to false cause the View to unload or is it handled in the Custom control? I too faced similar issue wanted to know your approach.

Comment: Nothing cause the unload. What I meant is that I dont need some views to load their content. By making use of control templates, you can change the appearance of the view without having content changes. Check my answer link. It works. I cannot set it as final answer until 2 days.

Answer (score 1):

You can define your visual states for normal screen, large screen etc, they will show or not depending on current state:

> Use the Visual State Manager to make changes to XAML elements based on
>   visual states set from code.
>
> The Visual State Manager (VSM) is new in Xamarin.Forms 3.0. The VSM
>   provides a structured way to make visual changes to the user interface
>   from code. In most cases, the user interface of the application is
>   defined in XAML, and this XAML includes markup describing how the
>   Visual State Manager affects the visuals of the user interface.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/visual-state-manager